# Websockets Using Spring + SockJS + STOMP on Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs, magnolia

I'm trying to implement some Websocket functionality for my web app running on Tomcat 7. I'm using the following tech:

- (server) Spring Websocket + Spring Messaging
- (client) SockJS + Stomp.js

I'm following this guide (roughly): http://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/

My configuration is similar to the guide, but I'll add some snippets of my code here:

Client:

```
    s.socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8181/.cckiosk/socket/test');
    //s.socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8181/.cckiosk/socket/test', {}, { transports: ['xhr-polling'] });
    s.client = Stomp.over(s.socket);
    s.client.connect({}, onConnect);
    s.client.onclose = onDisconnect;
```

Server:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class ModuleWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry broker) {
        //Prefix for messages FROM server TO client
        broker.enableSimpleBroker("/client");
        //Prefix for messages FROM client TO server
        broker.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/server");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket/test").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/socket/test")
@SendTo("/client/message")
public GenericMessage doSample(GenericMessage msg) {
    log.info("doSample: " + JsonUtil.jsonify(msg));
    return new GenericMessage(msg.getId(), msg.getMessage(), new Date());
}
```

I have everything set up in a vanilla Spring app, and everything works great.

However, when I port the same code over to a Magnolia module, the code stops working and I can see the following errors:

**Client-side error:**

[image: Client-side error]

**Server-side error:**

```
2015-09-19 16:28:43,412 DEBUG eb.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator: New WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=tde1syjd]
2015-09-19 16:28:43,413 DEBUG eb.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator: Transport error in WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=tde1syjd]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.BioServletInputStream.doRead(BioServletInputStream.java:37)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.read(AbstractServletInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:203)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:93)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It's actually either Connection Reset or Broken Pipe.

Changing the transport protocol to a non-websocket one (e.g. `xhr-polling`) also doesn't help.

Any idea what could be in Magnolia that's causing a long-lived Websocket session to have its connection closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution lay in simply bypassing the Magnolia filter chain altogether.

I just needed to create a global bypass object in Magnolia admincentral: Configuration > server/filters/bypasses

```
class: info.magnolia.StartsWithURIVoter
pattern: /socket
```

And the connection doesn't reset or get interrupted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In Mangolia 5 it is 'info.magnolia.voting.voters.URIStartsWithVoter', instead of 'info.magnolia.StartsWithURIVoter'